# Count occupancy per hour Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am trying to count the occupancy level per hour in a parking area and show it in a histogram. I have 4 months data and my data frame looks like this.

[image: Dataftame head]

Can I get any suggestion how to create the histogram?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column `hour` by applying `dt.hour()` to `'CarEntry'` and `'CarExit'` columns. Then `groupby(['BayNumber','hour'])`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be incorrect if a car was parked for multiple hours? Say it enters at hour 1, and leaves at hour 3. This solution doesn't count it as being present at hour 2.